# How to run a cmd command in python as an administrator?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, shell, cmd

I need to run these commands:

```
os.system('cmd /k "cd\"')
os.system('cmd /k "cd models/tutorials/image/imagenet"')
```

They need to be run as administrator in the system32 directory though. If I just type them into command prompt when running as admin, they do what they are supposed too, however, they do nothing when I run from python because the cmd needs to be run as admin for it to work. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: If you don't want to run the python script as administrator, put the commands inside an executable and run that instead of cmd. In that executable include a manifest file that requires administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, right click the py script and click `Run as Administrator`. It will give the script full permissions.

Dave S. also mentioned that you can package it as a `.exe` file requiring administrative access.